# Bootstrap: Collapse and Tooltip together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I want to know if its possible to have tooltip on a collapse anchor tag. The code which is use for collapse is:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Data</a>
```

It works fine but now I want to add a tooltip to it. So I changed the code to:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse tooltip" title ="Tooltip Message" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Data</a>
```

Now it shows the tooltip but the collapse function does not work. What changes I have to do so that both functionality works. I know the text of anchor tag can actually show the message I want to use as tooltip message but just want to know if its possible to have both functionality together

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap Javascript overview page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/):

> ## Component data attributes
>
> Don't use data attributes from multiple plugins on the same element. For example, a button cannot both have a tooltip and toggle a modal. To accomplish this, use a wrapping element.

Try this:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip Message">Data<span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to change trigger for tooltip. Default trigger is:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Which will work like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
```

But you can change it to:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-tooltip="true"]').tooltip()
})
```

Which will work like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-tooltip="true" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I have read the question =) The problem is that the button should have both a toggle and a tooltip trigger. 

So my suggestion is to change from the default bootstrap trigger to another trigger (data-tooltip="true"). Then it won't be in conflict with the toggle function.

Comment: I'd modify this slightly to just _add_ to this solution    $(function () {
  $('[data-tooltip="true"], [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})