# Set two elements, modal and popover, in data-toggle

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, popover

I'm facing a problem with getting a button to open a popver modal when hovering over and click.

```html
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-success btn-lg" 
        data-target="#addChangeModal" 
        data-toggle="####" 
        data-toggle="" 
        data-content="Add change">
</button>`
```

when I set data-toggle to

```html
data-toggle="modal"
```

or

```
data-toggle="popover"
```

Both values **modal**  and **popover** work perfectly.

However I am unable to set

```html
data-toggle="modal popover"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch your modal with jQuery:

```js
$('#my-btn').click(function () {
     $('#addChangeModal').modal('show');  
     $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide'); //EDIT: added this line to hide popover on button click.
});
```

And then use a standard popover from Bootstrap, include `data-trigger="hover"` to show popover on hover.

```html
<button id="my-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Popover Title" data-content="Popover content" data-toggle="popover"></button>
```

### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/YkYlqXn9ls)

Comment: Thanks and a little question to this: is there a way to turn off popover when opening modal? On computer browser it works but on mobile doesn't.

Comment: Yes, SEE EDIT, just added

Answer (score 5):

The official answer to this from the Devs of Bootstrap:

> Don't use data attributes from multiple plugins on the same element. For example, a button cannot both have a tooltip and toggle a modal. To accomplish this, use a wrapping element.

An example of this would be something like:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip Message">Data<span>
</a>
```

credit to: [Bootstrap: Collapse and Tooltip together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200652/bootstrap-collapse-and-tooltip-together)